# chrome making little square of div element invisible on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a script that resizes some div elements on my webpage when the page loads and when the window is resized. The problem is that when I change chrome from windowed to full screen(i don't mean F11 full screen mode just that it goes from edge to edge), a small part of the div becomes invisible. It doesn't happen in any other browser. I'm running the latest release of chrome.

The div that has this problem is #black_line_bottom and you can see the #bottom_container div in the down right corner.

code for resize (js):

```
function calcHeight(factor){
if($(window).height() > 720){
    return $(window).height() * factor / 100;
}
else{
    return 720 * factor / 100;
}
}

function getEl(x){
return document.getElementById(x)
}

function resizeHeight(){
var height = calcHeight(3.5);
getEl("black_line_bottom").style.height = height + "px";
getEl("white_line_bottom").style.bottom = height + "px";
height = calcHeight(7.8);
getEl("bottom_container").style.height = height + "px";
getEl("white_line_bottom").style.height = (height - calcHeight(3.5)) + "px";
height = calcHeight(20.5);
};

$(window).on( "resize ready" , resizeHeight);
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div id = "bottom_container" >
        <div id = "black_line_bottom" class = "black_line">

        </div>
        <div id = "white_line_bottom"class = "white_line">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.black_line {
position : fixed;
background-color : #0a0a0a;
width : 100%;
height : 41px;
left : 0px;
right : 0px;
}

#black_line_bottom {
bottom : 0px;
}

#bottom_container {
position : fixed;
width : 100%;
height : 90px;
left : 0px;
right : 0px;
bottom : 0px;
}

.white_line {
position : absolute;
background-color : red;
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
left : 0px;
right : 0px;
}

#white_line_bottom {
bottom : 41px;
}
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code and if possible create a full working example, perhaps using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). The question mentions a `<div>` but you haven't added any markup.

Comment: Sorry for that I'll add the relevant div and markup in a moment.

Comment: here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/QbTYe/.  I don't see any problems on chrome/mac

Comment: I don't see a problem here neither. But if you run it from a .html file you'll see it.

Comment: No problems for me on chrome/pc either.  On the pc, I do see a little white box flickering on the bottom right as I resize the window, but it disappears when the resize is done.

Comment: I can show you a screen shot if you want me to. Maybe it's a pc error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some research and it appears to be a bug in chrome.

Link to bug: 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151623

Comment: Which one? It would be a much more useful answer if you tell others about your findings...

Comment: Thank you and sorry for not doing it in the first place.